# Real time text processing using Python

Tags: python, performance, nlp, text-processing, nltk

Real time text processing using Python. For e.g. consider this sentance

```
I am going to schol today
```

I want to do the following (real time):

```
1) tokenize 
2) check spellings
3) stem(nltk.PorterStemmer()) 
4) lemmatize (nltk.WordNetLemmatizer())
```

Currently I am using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) library to do these operations, but its not real time (meaning its taking few seconds to complete these operations). I am processing 1 sentence at a time, Is it possible to make it efficient

Update:
Profiling:

```
Fri Jul  8 17:59:32 2011    srj.profile

         105503 function calls (101919 primitive calls) in 1.743 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 1797 to 10 due to restriction 

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     7450    0.136    0.000    0.208    0.000 sre_parse.py:182(__next)
  602/179    0.130    0.000    0.583    0.003 sre_parse.py:379(_parse)
23467/22658    0.122    0.000    0.130    0.000 {len}
 1158/142    0.092    0.000    0.313    0.002 sre_compile.py:32(_compile)
    16152    0.081    0.000    0.081    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     6365    0.070    0.000    0.249    0.000 sre_parse.py:201(get)
     4947    0.058    0.000    0.086    0.000 sre_parse.py:130(__getitem__)
 1641/639    0.039    0.000    0.055    0.000 sre_parse.py:140(getwidth)
      457    0.035    0.000    0.103    0.000 sre_compile.py:207(_optimize_charset)
     6512    0.034    0.000    0.034    0.000 {isinstance}
```

timit:

```
t = timeit.Timer(main)
print t.timeit(1000)

=> 3.7256231308
```

Comment: Have you bothered profiling yet?

Comment: That doesn't look like the most interesting part of the profiling.

Comment: oops sorry, I forgot to sort...updated again. thanks

Comment: Ok, so you posted profiling output, but how much input is `main` processing? A single sentence? Is processing 10 sentences 10x as slow? 100 sentences?

Comment: just processing one text(SMS) message. Max 160 chars.

Comment: I am very interested in your work. But I can not fully understand the step 4.
Would you mind paste the code in step 3 and step 4 ?

Answer (score 3):

NLTK's `WordNetLemmatizer` uses a [lazily-loaded WordNetCorpusReader](http://www.google.com/codesearch#LyqJbVaGnAY/trunk/nltk/nltk/corpus/__init__.py&q=LazyCorpusLoader%20package%3ahttp://nltk%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=217) (using a `LazyCorpusLoader`).  The first call to `lemmatize()` may take significantly longer than later calls if it triggers the corpus loading.

You could place a dummy call to `lemmatize()` to trigger the loading when your application starts up.

Comment: Thanks Josh, your suggestion sounds interesting. can you explain to me how to do the dummy call to Lemmatize().

Comment: @Mahin: I'd just call `lemmatize("")` with an empty string.  Because the corpus reader is shared among all `WordNetLemmatizer` instances, you don't have to use the same instance that you use in your application: a call to `nltk.WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize("")` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I know NLTK is slow, but I can hardly believe it's that slow. In any case, first stemming, then lemmatizing is a bad idea, since these operations serve the same purpose and feeding the output from a stemmer to a lemmatizer is bound to give worse results than just lemmatizing. So skip the stemmer for an increase in both performance and accuracy.

Comment: you could lemmatize, then stem, which can sometimes produce a smaller string than either method alone

Answer (score 1):

No way it's that slow. I bet what's happening is loading the tools and data to do the stemming etc. As said earlier, run a few tests- 1 sentence, 10 sentences, 100 sentences.

Alternatively, the Stanford parser can do the same stuff and might be a bit quicker being Java based (or LingPipe) but NLTK is waaaaaay more user friendly.